# JavaScript code won't send email using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a JS code as below :

```
function validateForm(){


 // some code 
 $.get("../sendMail.php");

 alert('Reached here ? then the mail was sent successfully');
 // more stuff

}
```

and the `sendMail.php` code :

```
<?php
$to = "someone@gmail.com";
$subject = "MY PHP MESSAGE";

$name = $_REQUEST['myName"'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['myPhone'];
$email = $_REQUEST['myEmail'];

$message .= "<br>"."<br>";

$message .= "<strong><font color='red'>Information Below.</font></strong>"."<br>"."<br>";

$message .= "<strong>Name:</strong> ".$name ."<br/>";
$message .="<strong>Phone:</strong> ".$phone."<br/>";
$message .="<strong>Email:</strong> ".$email."<br/>";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: michaeljackson@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);   
?>
```

Even though the alert in the JS works great , the mail is not sent .

Any idea what's wrong with the code ?

Much appreciated

**(FYI , I'm running on the localhost , if it makes any difference)**

**EDIT :**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../sendMail.php',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert(console.log('data: %O', data));
        alert(console.log('textStatus: %s', textStatus));
        alert(console.log('jqXHR: %O', jqXHR));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(console.log('jqXHR: %O', jqXHR));
        alert(console.log('textStatus: %s', textStatus));
        alert(console.log('errorThrown: %s', errorThrown));
    }});
```

but nothing was sent , and nothing is being printed on the screen . No alert , nothing .

Comment: You didn't send any parameters in your `$.get` call.

Comment: Make sure you have a local mail server, because PHP's mail() function sends with the current machine's mail server...

Comment: Your script isn't checking whether `mail()` was successful. Check the Network tab of Developer Tools to see if the script reported any errors.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `.get` method is *asynchronous*.  Meaning that the `alert` will appear whether the AJAX call is successful or not.  What you need is this:

```
$.get('../sendMail.php', function(data){
    console.log('Reached here ? then the mail was sent successfully');
}):
```

Incidentally, `.get` is a convenience alias for `.ajax`.  If you're having trouble, you should use `.ajax`, which gives you more options for debugging:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../sendMail.php',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log('data: %O', data);
        console.log('textStatus: %s', textStatus);
        console.log('jqXHR: %O', jqXHR);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('jqXHR: %O', jqXHR);
        console.log('textStatus: %s', textStatus);
        console.log('errorThrown: %s', errorThrown);
    }
});
```

See the [documentation for `.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for all the options available to you.

Comment: See my edit.  I gave you some avenues for collecting extra information.

Comment: Add the code I suggested, then report back with what you see on the log.  It will help us fix the problem.

Comment: Are you looking at the console log?  I'm just not sure what you mean when you say "nothing is printed to the screen".  There should be _something_....

Comment: I added another alert after the code you posted , and the alert works , but the code before that (your code) is not invoked ... I guess . I tried both with `console` and `alert` , but your code is not invoked .

Comment: Hm.  Something strange is definitely going on.  One of `success` or `error` should have been called.  Can you put something in your PHP code so you know that you're getting there?  Even a `file_put_contents("C:\\temp\\test.txt", "mail function called");` would suffice....

Comment: I put the line `file_put_contents("C:\\temp\\test.txt", "mail function called");` in the PHP file ,but the `test.txt` was not created . hmmm..

Comment: So that tells you that your PHP isn't being invoked at all.  I assume it works if you access it directly (with a browser)?

Answer (score 0):

You are also missing the parameters to send to the PHP file, it is waiting to receive:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['myName"'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['myPhone'];
$email = $_REQUEST['myEmail'];
```

So you should also send them on the request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../sendMail.php",
  data: { myName: "John Doe", myPhone: "123456789", myEmail: "loller@dude.com" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Mail sent: " + msg );
});
```

I suggest you to learn about the AJAX request and how jQuery does it:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX
- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Also refer on how PHP handles the $_REQUEST var:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Greets!

Answer (score -1):

Use this one,

```
var myName = $('#name').val(); //get from input fields
var myEmail = $('#email').val();
var myPhone = $('#phone').val();
$.ajax({
  url: "../sendMail.php", //url to send
  type:"get", //get or post
  data: "myName="+myName+"&myEmail="+myEmail+"&myPhone="+myPhone, //data to be send
  success:function(response){ //on success
    alert('Reached here ? then the mail was sent successfully');
  },
  error: function(response){ //on error
    alert(response);
  }
});
```